# how to set column(<td>) width using td value in table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to set td width using the value of td. I have simply created a dynamic table you can see below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="heading">Post Name</td>
        <td class="heading">Number of Post Available</td>
        <td class="heading">Age Limit</td>
        <td class="heading">Qualification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Junior Engineer</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>21-30</td>
        <td>You must have BE/B.tech degree in computer science with minimum 60% marks</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know which value come form mysql to table, some times the structure of table is change like this...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="heading">Post Name</td>
        <td class="heading">Number of Post Available</td>
        <td class="heading"></td>
        <td class="heading">Qualification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Junior Engineer</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>You must have BE/B.tech degree in computer science with minimum 60% marks</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So that I want to change the width of td using td value like..

If the value of td is qualification then width="40%" or else if the value is age then set width 10%.

I don't know is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options for how you could approach this depending on the flexibility you have with your markup.

**Take Advantage of Table Headers**

If you can adjust your existing markup / formatting, you could consider using table headers and applying the appropriate widths to those (either directly or through a CSS style), and these values will be reflected within the child cells of that column :

```css
table .heading {
  width: 10%;
}

table .qualification {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="heading">Post Name</th>
    <th class="heading">Number of Post Available</th>
    <th class="heading"></th>
    <th class="heading qualification">Qualification</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Junior Engineer</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>You must have BE/B.tech degree in computer science with minimum 60% marks</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Additionally, using this approach, you could probably forego the "heading" styles and instead just style them via the `<th>` elements instead.

**Consider CSS Selectors**

If the specific order of your cells isn't going to change, you could take advantage of the [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to target only the fourth column and use a prior selector to target all other elements :

```
table td { width: 10%; }
table td:nth-child(4) { width: 40%; }
```

```css
table td {
  width: 10%;
}

table td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="heading">Post Name</td>
    <td class="heading">Number of Post Available</td>
    <td class="heading"></td>
    <td class="heading">Qualification</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Junior Engineer</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>You must have BE/B.tech degree in computer science with minimum 60% marks</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It should still function and be rendered as expected (the `<td>` elements that is), so the CSS styles should still apply. If that's what you are referring to.

Comment: thank you, sir my problem is solved with your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to use `th` (Table Header) instead of the `td` tag with it's `width` attribute:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width="70%">Month</th>
    <th width="30%">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_width.asp

Comment: but sir don't want to define the width in internal css because I don't know which value is come in td or th ( actually column value come from mysql database)